# Should a business website include links to my social media accounts or display a feed?

Tags: design, social-media

Working on a business site for a client who does not sell their product/service online. They want to show that they have a social presence. They might have one or multiple. Are there any studies suggesting that showing feeds vs. buttons is the right way to go? I have my gut feeling but looking to bring in stats with the client meeting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is less so about usability and more about business strategy. What is the benefit of showing social media posts or presence and how are does is impact your sales funnel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question based on business requirements and not user expectations

Answer (score 0):

When you display a feed, visitors see only a part of posts from the account, which may be not perfect. When you link an account, they visit the page and see all posts including the context, which may help them to better understand your account.